# How to solve "ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape () instead." for Extremely Random Forest Regressor?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-learn, artificial-intelligence

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, mean_absolute_error
from sklearn import cross_validation, preprocessing
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

# Load input data
input_file = 'traffic_data.txt'
data = []
with open(input_file, 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        items = line[:-1].split(',')
        data.append(items)

data = np.array(data)

# Convert string data to numerical data
label_encoder = [] 
X_encoded = np.empty(data.shape)
for i, item in enumerate(data[0]):
    if item.isdigit():
        X_encoded[:, i] = data[:, i]
    else:
        label_encoder.append(preprocessing.LabelEncoder())
        X_encoded[:, i] = label_encoder[-1].fit_transform(data[:, i])

X = X_encoded[:, :-1].astype(int)
y = X_encoded[:, -1].astype(int)

# Split data into training and testing datasets 
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(
        X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=5)

# Extremely Random Forests regressor
params = {'n_estimators': 100, 'max_depth': 4, 'random_state': 0}
regressor = ExtraTreesRegressor(**params)
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Compute the regressor performance on test data
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
print("Mean absolute error:", round(mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred), 2))

# Testing encoding on single data instance
test_datapoint = ['Saturday', '10:20', 'Atlanta', 'no']
test_datapoint_encoded = [-1] * len(test_datapoint)
count = 0
for i, item in enumerate(test_datapoint):
    if item.isdigit():
        test_datapoint_encoded[i] = int(test_datapoint[i])
    else:
        test_datapoint_encoded[i] = int(label_encoder[count].transform(test_datapoint[i]))
        count = count + 1 

test_datapoint_encoded = np.array(test_datapoint_encoded)

# Predict the output for the test datapoint
print("Predicted traffic:", int(regressor.predict([test_datapoint_encoded])[0]))
```

**
Error seems to occur inside the else part of second for loop but can't figure out the cause:

File "F:\Python_Workspace\AI\traffic_prediction.py", line 114, in 
test_datapoint_encoded[i] = int(label_encoder[count].transform(test_datapoint[i]))

File "C:\Users\BISWADEEP\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing_label.py", line 133, in transform
y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)

File "C:\Users\BISWADEEP\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 63, in inner_f
return f(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\BISWADEEP\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 864, in column_or_1d
raise ValueError(

ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape () instead.
**

Answer (score 0):

Could you writte what is the number of line with error and try to check shape of the input array - it looks like input is empty. Sometimes to predict value you should reshape array for the model.:
reshaped_array=np.reshape(some_array,(-1,1))

Comment: Sorry for late reply.Here's the line no. of the error:
  File "F:\Python_Workspace\AI\traffic_prediction.py", line 61, in <module>
    test_datapoint_encoded[i] = int(label_encoder[count].transform(test_datapoint[i]))

Comment: I think the book that I am following has older version of Python that's why all the codes are not working in the new version.

Comment: Which array should I reshape? I have tried to reshape both X and y but most of the time it throws ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples

Comment: Shape of X is (17568, 4) and Shape of y (17568, )

Comment: Shape() from error suggest You have empty array. What is linę od error on your code?